# Using inpaint for stitching

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm capturing bio-cells in high magnification using 5MP camera.
As the cells are "swimming" in glycerine not on the same level, I'm making a stack of images in range of +/- 5u around the focus position and "stitch" the tiles with best sharpness from different levels together in one image.

Unfortunately, sometimes one can see the edges between the tiles when the image is zoomed.

Yet, I've read about inpaint function in OpenCV and wonder if it would help to make the edges invisible.

So, could inpaint help in my case? If yes, is there also a threat, that it could remove some proper part of the image (e.g. cell-membrane visible as a very thin, bright line)?

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: I think it might help, assuming you have masks of the edges you would like blended. Do you happen to have some sample images?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've made some experiments and result did look worse with inpainting than without. Without inpainting you could mostly see the edges only in magnified view. With inpainting the changes in the images were visible even in not-zoomed view.

Another thing is, as I can't measure the degree of edge-error, I had to apply inpainting on all edges - even where the transition between tile was nearly invisible. This resulted in a clearly visible grid.